# ZKSForce Update sales force object

Tags: ios, swift, salesforce

I have a problem using [ZKSForce](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce) SDK. I would like to update an object from sales force.

I have found a the way to **update a sales force object** in objective-c.
[Example Online Here](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2012/01/developing-ios-application-for.html)

```
 ZKSObject *sfobj = [[ZKSObject alloc] initWithType:@"Your_custom_object__c"] ;    

    [sfobj setType:@"Your_custom_object__c"];
    [sfobj setFieldValue:@"a0FM0000000XrKcMAK" field:@"Id"];
    [sfobj setFieldValue:@"PAL-008" field:@"Service_code__c"]; 
    [sfobj setFieldValue:@"Room heating system" field:@"Name"];   //update the field value required
    [sfobj setFieldValue:@"Maintenance" field:@"Service_Status__c"];
    [sfobj setFieldValue:@"a07M0000000FV5VIAW" field:@"child_of_another_custom_object__c"];

     [[FDCServerSwitchboard switchboard] update:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sfobj] target:self selector:@selector(updatedObjectResult:error:context:) context:nil];
```

However, I am trying to do this in **Swift 4**. In the code below is how I gain access to sales force and retrieve data, but I don't know how to implement the objective-c code above to update the data.

```
    //Initial Access to Salesforce in order to query data
    client.performLogin(accessUsername, password: accessPassword, fail:{ (fail) in

    }) { (success) in

        let getCasesSQL = "put getcases here"
        self.queryResult = self.client.query(getCasesSQL)

         for o: Any in self.queryResult.records() {

          //How im retrieving an object
          let currentUserID = ((o as AnyObject).fieldValue("Id"))!

}
```

I tried imitating the objective-c code but I am very confused with the **objects and casting** trying to understand whats really going on.

```
let sfobject = ZKSObject()
 sfobject.setType("Lender__c")
 sfobject.setId(clientData.userID)
 sfobject.setFieldValue("Test" as NSObject, field: "State__c")
 sfobject.fieldValue("State__c")
  print(sfobject)
self.client.update([sfobject])
//Printing Lender__c "userID" fields=(null) toNull=(null)
```

Comment: Based on that implementation it seems like it should be `sfobject.setFieldValue("a0FM0000000XrKcMAK", field: "Id")`.  Does that not work?

Comment: no it does not. i feel like it would be through the client similar to retrieving the data. Ive tried everything i just cant figure it out.